Ubuntu 22.04.4 running very slow after update from 22.04.2
I am using ubuntu 22.04.4 and I've noticed that after upgrading to this current version that the machine runs extremely slow from 22.04.2.
The base CPU clock always goes down to the minimum and causes the computer to lag.
Any idea what changed that could of made this issue occur?
I have attached some screen shots for reference.
CPU info:

System info:

Edit 1:

Edit 2:
When running the task: taskset -c 0 yes > /dev/null
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
5500000

When not running the task: taskset -c 0 yes > /dev/null
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
800000


anyone have an idea about this?

Which CPU frequency scaling driver are you using? Do: grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver . Which CPU frequency scaling governor are you using? Do grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor. Some other useful info might be grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/* and  (if intel_pstate driver) grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/*

I'm having the same issue of an extremely slow/laggy UI. My CPU is a i5-13600K. The scaling_governor is reported to be "powersave" for all cores, altough power settings are set to performance in the GUI. I can not confirm the low clock speed though. My cores are at a steady 3.5Ghz with occasional boosts according to watch -n.1 "cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep \"^[c]pu MHz\"". Any new insights?

@Fitzi : Please start your own question and include the information I asked for in my comment. Also include the kernel version and the output from grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq. Your issue doesn't sound like low CPU frequency is the cause.

@DougSmythies
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
Odd thing is I don't have powersave selected on my power option
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/hwp_dynamic_boost:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct:100
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct:14
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/status:active

The powersave governor with the intel_pstate driver is similar to the ondemand governor for the intel_cpufreq driver. Please edit your question adding all the information I asked for in my earlier comments, both to you and to Fitzi.

@DougSmythies done and edited

To see of the CPU frequency is being throttled, let's do a specific test: In one terminal do taskset -c 0 yes > /dev/null and while that is running in another terminal do cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq. Edit your question adding the text of the results, not as screen shots.

@DougSmythies
Edit 2 done as requested.
Could this be related to the linux kernal being upgrade to 6.5.0?
Can you explain why the GUI that changes the power modes would be reflected in the governor?

Under full load a CPU, cpu 0 in this test case, scales its frequency up to 5.5 GHz as expected. And it idles down to 0.8 GHz with the load removed, also as expected. Everything seems normal.

So powersave works but if I want performance governor at all times because it raises the idle. How do I change that @DougSmythies

echo performance | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor will change the governor, but the change will not persist across re-boots. There are utilities for taking care of things across re-boots, but I don't use them. Note that even with the performance governor the processor itself can reduce the CPU frequency if the load is light enough.

@DougSmythies so the GUI interface on the power options doesn't affect cpu scaling?

I don't know, I am a server person and do not use any GUI stuff.
